# PHP 7 Module already loaded warnings

Tags: php, php-fpm, php7, php-cli

I have a machine running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS that is deployed via Ansible. I've got PHP 7 installed using [Ondřej Surý's PPA for PHP](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i php
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.0            7.0.3-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-common                       1:36+deb.sury.org~trusty+1       all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php7.0                           7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.0-cli                       7.0.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                    7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.0-fpm                       7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.0-json                      7.0.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                   7.0.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-pgsql                     7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+1    amd64        PostgreSQL module for PHP
```

#### The warnings

When cron runs `/usr/lib/php/sessionclean`, I get the following warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

When running `php -v` I get a subset of those warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'calendar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ctype' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ftp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gettext' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'iconv' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'Phar' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'posix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sockets' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvmsg' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvsem' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sysvshm' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'tokenizer' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

And occasionally in the logs for CodeIgniter I get the line:

```
Severity: Core Warning --> Module 'tokenizer' already loaded Unknown 0
```

#### The config files

This error is not a new one so I've had plenty of other questions to look at, but the solution they suggest is to make sure there aren't any duplicate `extension=...` lines in my `php.ini` but there aren't any.

Here are all the files in `/etc/php`. There are a bunch of `ini` files for individual modules linked to in multiple places that are likely causing the issue.

```
/etc/php/mods-available/json.ini
/etc/php/mods-available/opcache.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/* -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/*
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/* -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/*
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.ucf-dist
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/* -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/*
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pgsql.ini
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini
```

**Which of these files do I need to delete to stop the warnings without stopping PHP working (via web and CLI)?** (bonus points if this is easily done via Ansible)

Comment: I have the same problem. And if I remove any of those ini files then the extension is not loaded at all. Did you finally figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the .ini files in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ to nameofthemodule.ini.back

Per example:
sudo mv tokenizer.ini tokenizer.ini.back

Restart php, then check php -m and check if the warning for that module is gone.

It seems that when installing an extension the php-common is installed too, this install then makes new .ini files for the extensions included. But those extensions are already compiled in the php binary.

Process with caution, the above paragraph is just a guess.

Comment: Removing them all seems to do the trick, and nothing else appears to have broken. Any idea why `php7.0-common` installs those config files by default if they're built into the binary? Is there an easy way to get Ansible not to install them?

Comment: Whoops, spoke too soon. My web-app can't find PDO now :/